# NavigationController presenting ViewController twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I installed third party library using pods, which has it's own navigationController.  I my existing project I am setting the rootViewController in the app delegate.  I am pushViewController to the library ViewController (which is in it's own navigation stack).  When I exit and then push to the library for a second time the ViewAlready seems to be there before transitioning the same view over the top. 
In my appDelegate...

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    appbarViewController = [[AppBarViewController alloc] init];
    [self loadNormalFlow];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)loadNormalFlow
{
    self.navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:appbarViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigation;
    [self.navigation setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

-(void)displayLibraryView
{
ACSViewController *acs = [[ACSViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigation pushViewController:acs animated:nil];
}
```

Within library ViewController class to return back to original rootViewController i am using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:@selector(loadNormalFlow)];
```

I seems like it is not properly dismissing the library ViewController, or it does a push twice?  Any idea?

Comment: I reckon it's because you're repeatedly setting the `rootViewController` on your window. If you presented your `ACSViewControllrer` using a navigation stack push, then you should dismiss it with a pop.

Comment: That seems to be it, but the library when called is replacing the rootViewController with its own.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: So is the problem that `ACSViewController` is a `UINavigationController` subclass?

Comment: Or is `ACSViewController` actually accessing the app delegate and setting the root view controller? Can you link me to the pod?

Comment: It's a private repo so won't be able to access it.  ACSViewController is a class I created which loads in the library ViewController which I created using it's own navigationController.  This makes it a UINavigationSubclass?

Comment: No. But it sounds like `ACSViewController` contains a `UINavigationController` then? I'm just trying to get a mental picture of your view controller hierarchy. I don't yet see why your `ACSViewController` can't just do `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]` (or `YES`) to dismiss...

Comment: ACSViewController i created to load the library and yes contains it's own UINavigationController. It looks like the UINavigationController that is set here replaces the original one created in the AppDelegate, so it doesn't return to it? I want to dismiss from with in the library. I did try using NotificationCenter to call a method in ACSViewController but with no success, I

Comment: Right, I think I get it. I imagine that the behaviour of nested navigation controllers is somewhat undefined and it normally suggests that there's something weird in your design. Saying that, it sounds like your hand may be being forced by the library you're using? In any case, have you tried `[((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).navigation popViewControllerAnimated:NO]`?